# fromevent (rxjs): return false when there is no scroll activity on a container for a certain period of time else emit true on scrolling

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a situation where my code has to return a true value when a user is scrolling and if the user has not scrolled for last 5 secs then the code must return false. Now it's very easy with vanilla js - *addeventlistener and timeout*. But I want to write this using **RxJs**. Can someone help ?

```js
container.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    this.holdAutoScroll = true;
  clearTimeout(this.timeOutID);
  this.timeOutID = setTimeout(() => {
    this.holdAutoScroll = false;
      }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: please provide a code example of what you already have ;)

Comment: Added the vanilla js code. Need to write it using rxjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's even easier with RxJS:

```
fromEvent(container, 'wheel').pipe(
  tap(() => this.holdAutoScroll = true),
  switchMapTo(timer(5000))
).subscribe(() => {
  this.holdAutoScroll = false;
})
```

- `fromEvent` will give you a stream of wheel events
- `tap` is called for every event
- `switchMapTo` will subscribe to another observable and cancel the previous subscription (this is basically what you did with `clearTimeout`)
- `timer(5000)` will emit an event once after 5 seconds
- `subscribe` is called after the timer emits the event

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation using [`timeout`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout) operator to throw an error if the event doesn't emit for 5 seconds.

```
fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  timeout(5000),
  map(_ => true),
  catchError(_ => of(false)),
  repeat()
).subscribe(
  res => {
    // res `true` - on scroll events
    // res `false` - if the event isn't triggered for 5 seconds
  }
);
```

Since we are returning [`of(false)`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) (an observable with a single emission) from the [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operator, the subscription will complete upon a `timeout` error. So we use [`repeat`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeat) operator to trigger the source event again.

Also from the `scroll` event [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event):

> `scroll` events can fire at a high rate

So we use [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) operator with a limit of 300ms to restrict the amount of notifications.

#### Demonstration

```js
var { fromEvent, of } = rxjs;
var { debounceTime, map, catchError, timeout, repeat } = rxjs.operators;

var inputBox = document.getElementById('search');
var displayBox = document.getElementById('display');

fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  timeout(5000),
  map(_ => true),
  catchError(_ => of(false)),
  repeat()
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the **4** steps below:

```js
fromEvent(container, 'wheel') // <= 1
  .pipe(
    mapTo(true), // <= 2
    timeoutWith(5000, of(false)), // <= 3
    repeat() // <= 4
  )
```

**1.**
`fromEvent` returns an Observable to which you can subscribe and receive notifications (of scroll events in the current context )

**2.** 
`mapTo` is used to transform each emitted notification to `true`

**3.** 
`timeoutWith` subscribes to second Observable (`of(false)`) if no emission occurs in 5 seconds, we simply replace the `fromEvent` Observable with another Observable  which returns `false` and completes (stops receiving notifications) immediately.

**4.**
 `repeat` is used to **re**-subscribe again to `fromEvent` in case `fromEvent` has been replaced with `of(false)` (as a result of the `timeoutWith`),

Here's a ****[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-heyrovsky-7lepn?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)****